# Все русские символы превратились в "кириллицу"

Tags: c++, кириллица

писал код сам используя русские символы, но чрз неделю они превратились в такую штуку, как исправить сразу весь код?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: открыть файл в правильной кодировке (судя по всему cp1251 вместо iso8859-1)

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже всё исправил)

Comment: @Андрей, если вопрос решен, добавьте ответ/решение и закройте вопрос, пожалуйста

Comment: "Русские символы" - это и есть кириллица. У вас на скриншоте латиница с диактрическими символами.

Answer (score 1):

Открыть файл в правильной кодировке (судя по всему cp1251 вместо iso8859-1).
Или изменить кодировку в свойствах проекта.